# Lodash debounce in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, lodash

I'm new with lodash and I'm trying to use it as below:

```
import _ from "lodash"
import SearchBar from "../components/UI/SearchBar"

const FaQSearchBar = () => {
  const handleOnChange = (e) => {
    console.log("pre-lodash")
    _.debounce(() => console.log("yo", e), 300)
  }

  return (
    <SearchBar
      initialWidth="204px"
      onFocusWidth="408px"
      onChange={handleOnChange}
    />
  )
}
export default FaQSearchBar
```

The pre lodash log pops but nothing from lodash itself. If i change the syntax for something like: `_.debounce(console.log("yo", e), 300)`

I have the following error *Uncaught TypeError: Expected a function*

I guess I'm missing a lodash principle here. Thanks

Comment: Your creating a debounced function, but then never calling it.  What you probably want to do is create your debounce function in a `useMemo`,

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Because you are using `debounce` in the wrong way. `Debounce` will return a function. If `handleOnChange` doesnt make component rerender, you can use:

```
  const functionDebounce = _.debounce(() => console.log("yo", e), 300);
  const handleOnChange = (e) => {
    console.log("pre-lodash");
    functionDebounce(e);
  };
```

But in reality, we will do something and the component will re-render. So we need to wrap `functionDebounce` into [useCallback](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usecallback) to make sure it not change when component rerender

```
const functionDebounce = useCallback(
    _.debounce(() => console.log("yo", e), 300),
    []
  );
```